# .NET web application on Windows 2008 R2 Webserver only able to address 16 GB RAM, not 32 - why?

Tags: asp.net, memory, windows-server-2008, out-of-memory

We are trying to run a .NET 4 web application (on an 8 GB, 8 core Windows 2008 R2 64bit Webedition server) that creates Word mailmerge documents, using Spire.doc. Everything works fine up to around 5.000 records. If we try to merge more, physical as well as virtual memory both consume all they can, around 8 GB each.

Question: according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#physical_memory_limits_windows_server_2008_r2, **Windows 2008 R2 64bit would give you 32 GB.**

**So how can I make the application use more virtual memory?**

Here's the code, but I think the question is rather generic (and yes, creating Word documents with 10.000 pages may seem ridiculous, but this is what the customer desires, and yes, we will talk him out of it):

```
    private static void Merge(DataTable recipients, string template, string saveAs)
    {
        Document document = new Document();
        document.LoadFromFile(template);

        document.MailMerge.Execute(recipients);

        document.ViewSetup.DocumentViewType = DocumentViewType.PrintLayout;
        document.SaveToFile(saveAs, FileFormat.Doc);
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure that more memory is going to efficiently solve your problem.  I think the correct solution is to create an asynchronous queue, push chunked jobs (of say 500 or so recipients at a time) onto the queue, and have a worker (or workers as you can scale horizontally with more machines) process these jobs.  After pushing all the merge jobs onto the queue, push in a final job to combine all of the generated documents into a single document if that is a requirement.

Comment: @cfeduke: Thanks, and yes, there will be other solutions to the problem, not necessarily async ones. We could probably create chunks of, as you say, 500 each and then merge them into one document (though this may need lots of memorey as well). But still, issues like this may be easier to solve with more accessible memory, and the theoretical question remains why only 16 GB are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to compile your web application in in x64 mode.

Comment: Interesting idea. I'll try that tomorrow.

Comment: Too bad, doesn't work. The 3rd party component is 32 bit. However, shouldn't a 32 bit application still be able to address more than 16 GB?

Comment: Then it'd be up to the 3rd party vendor to deliver a 64 bit version.